# SharePoint and DataBase Design

Tags: sharepoint

I don't know about SharePoint that much, so hope that someone can give me some good explanations for me.

1. For SharePoint application, we don't need to consider SharePoint DB design? Everything is done through List and SharePoint will take care of the Database? Don't need to consider it at all unless we are connecting to the external Database?
2. For Parent Child relationship, I have to use **lookup** field?
3. If we are developing using Web parts, we need to deploy it using Features. So eventually, there can be so many features in the production? Is it recommended in this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1)
>
> For SharePoint application, we don't need to consider SharePoint DB
>   design ? Everything is done through List and SharePoint will take care
>   of the Database ? Don't need to consider it at all unless we are
>   connecting to the external Database ?

You do need to consider the database... In term of administration. back ups, restore, size and so on. 
however you never directly read or write to it. You don't need to pay attention to the schema because you won't ever be directly using it. If you want to update something in SharePoint you do it pragmatically with c# / vb.net using the SharePoint API's. You have 2 API's one that works on the server called the SharePoint object model and one that works on a remote machine called the client side object model.
From a users perspective, you are correct lists contain data in SharePoint and are somewhat smiler to DB tables in some ways.

> 2)
>
> For Parent Child relationship, I have to use lookup field ?

Yip

> 3)
>
> If we are developing using Web parts, we need to deploy it using
>   Features. So eventually, there can be so many features in the
>   production ? Is it recommended in this way?

This can happen if you create a new solution for every web part but you can bundle multiple web parts in the same solution in the same project in the same feature
Right click on your project --> add new item. select a web part. By default the web parts will all be part of the same feature but you can separate them out and have multiple features in the same solution if you want to